# Android 6.0.1 periodic get gps location failed

Tags: android, gps

I would like yo create the background service for logging GPS location . When it comes to execution, it does not give me any periodic data,no matter at office or on street or on the country side. Would you please tell me the way to get GPS location for every n seconds ? I have sometimes acquired the exception Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation got.

My code is set up as follows :

```
    public class TaskpointActivity extends FragmentActivity implements  LocationListener,
      GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter   {

        private static final long POLLING_FREQ = 1000 * 2;


    private LocationManager mLocationManager  ;  
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {

...


    mLocationManager = (LocationManager)  this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);        

              mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                      LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, POLLING_FREQ,    1, this);

              mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                      LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, POLLING_FREQ,   1, this);

        } catch (Exception ex) { 
            SystemUtils.takeLog(this, ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }       
}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "onStatusChanged PROVIDER:" + provider + " STATUS:" + String.valueOf(status));

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "onProviderEnabled PROVIDER:" + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "onProviderDisabled PROVIDER:" + provider);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(mLastLocation !=null) {
               deviceSpeed = Math.sqrt(  Math.pow(location.getLongitude() - mLastLocation.getLongitude(), 2)
                               + Math.pow(location.getLatitude() - mLastLocation.getLatitude(), 2)
               ) / (location.getTime() - this.mLastLocation.getTime());
        }else{
              mLastLocation = location;
        }

          if (location.hasSpeed())
               deviceSpeed = location.getSpeed();

        SystemUtils.takeLog(this , "location latitude  : " + location.getLatitude() );
        SystemUtils.takeLog(this , "location longitude  : " + location.getLongitude()  );
        SystemUtils.takeLog(this , "location speed device  : " + location.getSpeed() );
        SystemUtils.takeLog(this , "location speed calculated  : " +  deviceSpeed  );

        LatLng startPosition = markerSingle!=null ? markerSingle.getPosition() :
                new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());

        if(executeFollowMe) {


            double latitu = startPosition.latitude;
            double longitu = startPosition.longitude  ;

            int fixed = 30;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < 30 ; i ++) {

                if(i < 10) { // east
                    longitu = longitu + (i+1) * 0.000003;
                }else if(i >=10 && i < 20) { // curve
                    int incre = i+1 ;
                    longitu = longitu +  incre  * 0.000003;
                    latitu = latitu + (fixed- incre) * 0.000003;
                }else if(i >=20 && i < 30) { // north
                    latitu = latitu + (i+1) * 0.000003;
                }
                LatLng currentPostion = new LatLng (latitu , longitu) ;
                prepareFollowMe(currentPostion);    
                //startPosition
            }

            SystemUtils.takeLog(TaskpointActivity.this,  markerSingle!=null ? "prepare Follow me mock" :  "prepare Follow me real device");
            //LatLng positionX

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes i was also faced this problem. It occure when we using

> targetSdkVersion 23

in our

> build.gradle

file.

When you need to get user Location simultaneously then you need to get permission runtime then you can use

> shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()

this method check if user give permission for allow previously in our app then it will not show again permission box front of the user. it show either user giving permission first time or if they give denny previously.

for more information check it : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

and one more way to solve it just set your

> targetSdkVersion 22

insted of

> targetSdkVersion 23

.

Comment: I have changed to targetSdkVersion 22 , and test with Android 6.0.1 . still no periodic report of location

Comment: @Raju Gujarati Create one Service and in **onStartCommand()**  call one custom **GPSTracker**  class to get the Current lat.,long. periodically